# How to determine if user has ssh keys in a perl script

Tags: perl, ssh, ssh-keys, tcsh

I have the following script in `tcsh` that looks like this:

```
df=`ssh $some_server 2>/dev/null df $2 -k` 
echo $df
```

`Perl` script runs this `tcsh` script and I have the two following questions:

1. What does the first command do?
2. How can I determine if I have the ssh keys, before running this command (from the `perl` script for example, or the `tcsh` script?

As I understand, If I don't have the ssh keys, it will ask for the password. I would like to print a basic warning to the user if he doesn't have the ssh keys.

Comment: Running a perl program that shells out to run ssh manually and try to understand the error conditions will give you a lot of headaches. At least have a look at the `system()` call where you can pass a list of parameters, so that you do not use the shell. Modules like `IPC::Run` may also help you write this more cleanly, specially when needing to deal with STDOUT/STDERR. Also, you have various Perl libraries that gives you SSH protocol features, either as rewritten or as a layer on top of it.Have a look at them, even if the question "do we have the proper keys" is complicated(depends on config)

Comment: You can use `-o BatchMode=yes` to check if passwordless login is possible. For example: `ssh -o BatchMode=yes userName@server true >/dev/null 2>&1 || echo "Passwordless login is not possible"`. See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/246794/45537) answer for more information

Answer (score 1):

When `ssh` fails to establish a connection to the server it doesn't tell you the reason, but you can run it in verbose mode and analyze the output afterwards.

For instance, use the following command:

```
ssh -vvv -i $path_to_key -o BatchMode=yes \
    -l $remote_user $remote_host echo ok 2>error.log
```

And afterwards, if it fails, check `error.log` for the cause of the problem.

Note that the debugging output may change between different `ssh` versions, so any solution that depends on it is never going to be very robust. You should consider it just a hint.